# Get image height from x point in swift

Tags: swift, height

I'm making another Swift game. The floor is the desert.
This floor is a physicsbody (sprite kit) based on it's image texture.
I want to know the height of the floor based on a specific x point (by instance the middle of the screen).
If i use floor.size.height it gets the height like it is a rectangle (in other words, the maximum height possible).
I want to get this Y point to make the player move upon it with physicsbody.

can anyone help with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need. Just because you are using the physics, it's simply stating the floor with `isDynamic = false` and players with `isDynamic = true` and the other parameters as for example:

```
enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
    case player1 = 1
    case player2 = 2
    case floor = 4
}

floor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.floor.rawValue
floor.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
floor.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

player1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.player1.rawValue
player1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.floor.rawValue
player1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.floor.rawValue
```

This is only a point to start so hope it helps you.

Comment: actually the physics is working fine also as the contact handling...
the floor is stable with Dynamic false and players are moving with Dynamic true...
but if i use this: player.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 10, y: 0, duration: 0)) the player may move into the floor on a uphill

Comment: You shouldn't use SKAction.move..with physics if you don't want unexpected behaviours. Instead use the applyImpulse or change velocity of your sprites..